# Lotus Notes: Automatically mark as read

Tags: email

I've tried using an agent to automatically mark all incoming e-mails as read but it doesn't appear to be working. Any suggestions?

Comment: wow. someone still using lotus bloats! amazing :)  sorry I wish I could remember how.

Answer (score 0):

Create an "Agent" under the "Create" menu.

Look at "Creating the Mark incoming mail" [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/mail-markup/)